# Using a while loop to iterate through a char array received as a parameter in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, pointers

I'm still a little new to C, and one hiccup I've been stuck on for the past bit is iterating through a char array received as a parameter. The char array was created as a String literal and passed as an argument. From my understanding this array being received as simply a pointer to the first element in the array; my goal is to loop through each element until reaching the end of the String literal that was passed.

Since I'm required to perform comparisons of each char to char literals inside the loop, I've assigned the value being pointed at in the array, to a char variable that is being used for the comparisons.

Where I'm having trouble is specifying at what point this loop should end.

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    testString("the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void testString(char line[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char ch;
    ch = line[i];

    char charArray[128];

    while (ch != '\0')    // Not sure why this doesn't work
    {   

        if ((ch == '\'' || ch == '-'))
        {
            charArray[j] = ch;
            j++;
        }
        else if (isalpha(ch))
        {
            charArray[j] = ch;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
             // do nothing
        }

        i++;
        ch = line[i];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

Comment: and learn how to use a debugger

Comment: The program will terminate when the loop finds the end mark of the string. The end of string is represented by '\0'.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?  It looks like the loop terminates fine - you just don't do anything with the resulting `charArray`.  (note that if/when you do something with `charArray` you'll probably need to make sure it's properly terminated with a null character which isn't happening now).

Comment: @pm100 it's already inside the loop, although badly indented.

Comment: It might be wise to check that `j` does not exceed the bounds of `charArray` - i.e. 127.

Comment: Could even be simplified to `while (ch) {...}`.

Answer (score 3):

The exit condition for your loop is working fine.

The only thing missing is that you need to null terminate `charArray` after the `while` loop and print it out:

```
while (ch != '\0')
{
    ...
}
charArray[j] = '\0';
printf("charArray=%s\n",charArray);
```